# MVC3 and ACS ClaimsIdentity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, azure, acs

I've been playing about with Azure ACS and its very cool and I think I'm going to use it in my next project..

One question I have though is when I get my ClaimsIdentity back, its pretty empty with just email and name.. is this by design?

Is it possible to get more information in this? I was really hoping I could use the avatar the user has for the service..

any help would be great.

cheers.
ste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The claims returned are pretty much at the discretion of the identity providers.  Each one can return different claims (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg185971.aspx for details on what each identity provider returns).  You’re only guaranteed to get the ‘Name Identifier’ and ‘Identity Provider’ claims returned by every Identity Provider.

More helpful information at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg185933.aspx.

Comment: Thanks for that, is there anyway you can get more information or would it be better using something like OpenAuth for this?

Answer (score 1):

As @mcollier wrote, the supplied claims are typically dependent of what the IdP's offer. However, you can enrich the security token in ACS and add arbitrary claims. You can write a rule that states:

"when someone authenticates with Google with an **email=someone@gmail.com**, issue a claim of type **role** with value **manager**"

So you could add anything (including an avatar) in a rule like this.

ACS is in essence a "normalizer" of claims that will translate claims in a token coming from the any IdP into something your app wil understand.

Note that IdPs that are under your control (e.g. your own ADFS server or a 3rd party IdP from a company) *could* supply additional claims. It is the pre-provisioned ones that are typically limited (e.g. e-mail, name, id).

You can define the transformation rules yourself using the ACS portal, the API or through 3rd party tools (that use the API) like [Auth10](http://www.auth10.com).